# Chrome Seems To Get Authentication/Credentials/Permissions Stuck

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, credentials

I've run into the same issue a few times now & I'm not sure what the problem is or why.

### The Situation:

1. In Chrome I login to a site, or use a site that stores some sort of cookie
2. Something changes, either I change a password, the server is restarted, or I change the Local IP of the server in question
3. The site does not work properly, I may get "User authentication failed" even though the user & password are correct, even when using a saved password, the site may get stuck on a loading prompt
4. Using Incognito Mode it works the way I expect
5. No matter what I do the problem persists, restarting chrome, restarting the computer, restarting the server, clearing browsing data, cookies, etc, all fail to resolve the problem.

### An Example:

1. I installed a Buffalo LinkStation into my network
2. It's DHCP address was 192.168.1.126
3. I kept the default password as I wanted to start with updating the firmware & setting the Network before anything else
4. I changed the DHCP reservation to have the NAS reserved on 192.168.1.33
5. I go to 192.168.1.33 & attempt to login
6. I receive the following error "User authentication failed"
7. I verify the defaults & receive the same error
8. I login on my phone & set a new password. I save the username & password in Chrome
9. On the desktop browser when I attempt to login it pops up the saved username, but clicking it does not work
10. I open an Incognito Window & go to the page
11. I use the popup saved username & login successfully
12. In the main Chrome (Not Incognito) window I clear browsing data for the last 24 hours, restart the computer, then load the page again
13. I receive the same error
14. A few days later the site works as expected again

I have had the same issue happen on multiple devices

- 4 separate windows machines, 2 virtual windows machines running on a Proxmox Server, 1 Ubuntu machine

---

Now I assume there is a Chrome account setting that is having problems, but I cannot figure out what it is, or how to change it

---

### Another example:

1. I run a locally hosted Docker Container of Nightscout (An app that monitors Blood Sugar)
2. The site is hosted through Cloudflared to 2 separate URLs
3. Randomly 1 of the sites will be stuck on the loading page
4. I will [Ctrl]+Refresh the page but it is the same
5. I will restart the server, but it does not fix the problem
6. An incognito tab works
7. The other site, pointing to the same local point works without issue
8. The same site on a different device works fine
9. After a few days it will work again
10. Restarting the computer, the server, clearing browsing data, etc does not fix the problem
11. This happens randomly & lasts for a few days
12. This happens on multiple devices, for both of the sites, but never in my experience on more than 1 at any given time